# Common Request Logging JAR Across Multiple Spring Boot Projects

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I am trying to build a common request logging jar that can be used as a dependency across multiple Spring Boot projects for standardized request logging.

**Example**

- Project A has 2 controller endpoints
- Project B has 10 controller endpoints

Once the logging jar is added as a dependency to projects A & B, then when a request is handled by a controller, the following log message will be generated:

```
url="/api/locations", requestMethod="GET", ip="192.168.1.23", userAgent="curl/7.35.0"
```

I'm trying to minimize or eliminate the need for any actual code changes in projects A & B.

Do I need to implement an interceptor to accomplish this?  Spring AOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there's a couple of topics here.

1. Shared configuration.

What I've done is create a JAR with a `logback-spring.xml` config file under `src/main/resources`. Build that (or whatever config works for you) and have it as a dependency in your projects.

2. Consistent logging.

Here you can implement your own javax.servlet.Filter as a spring component, or use the `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` as provided by Spring. Instantiate it as a `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class and away you go.
NB: IIRC, this doesn't log responses or request bodies.